# Python ImportError: cannot import modules/classes

Tags: python, importerror

Copying the import lines from tap.py...

tap.py:

```
import site

import user

from site import security, agent

from site.security import models
```

When I run this i am getting:

```
  File "/home/vikasadmin/user/tap.py", line 31, in init

    from site import security, agent

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/site/security.py", line 9, in <module>

    from site import models

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/site/models.py", line 12, in <module>

    from site import config

ImportError: cannot import name config
```

Since I already imported models from site.security this config should have been included. Please explain? How can I solve this?

Comment: config doesn't seem to be directly under site. It may be under some other classes that you need to import first. Check your module arrangements.

Comment: what is site? are u using Django or other framwork ?